# Memory leak in matplotlib python - constatnt small increase in "for loop"

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, memory-leaks

I am suffering memory leak in my "for loop (over 1100 loops)" for creating maps.
I am not able to detect what is so memory hungry during the loops.
When I checked what could help - most commons hints were to use:

- `plt.clf()`
- `gc.collect()`

neither helped.

When I check loops by `psutil.Process(os.getpid()).memory_info().rss / 1024 ** 2` for memory usage, it constantly growing by 31 MB per loop, even when the loops aren't exactly same always (there are 4 possibilities/ways of creation of the maps). By `objgraph` I tryied to detect what is accumulating in memory, but I am not able to identify exactly what is happening. Here is output from `(objgraph.show_growth())`:

```
dict                          20565       +49
method                         1034       +26
list                           6886       +21
weakref                       11206       +20
tuple                         11657       +19
cell                           6584       +18
function                      22611       +17
builtin_function_or_method     5268       +13
WeakMethod                      232        +7
Bbox                            223        +6
```

Here is example of code (one of the 4) I use to create the maps:

```
def plot_map_lin (boundry, colm_var, shp, code_name):
   name_val = []
   vmin = 9999999
   vmax = 0
   for row in range(lencodes):
       cell = data.iloc[row][colm_var]
       name_val.append(float(cell) + abs(boundry[0]))
       if float(cell) > vmax:
           vmax = int(cell)
       elif float(cell) < vmin:
           vmin = int(cell)
   gdfdict[colm_var] = name_val
   df = pd.DataFrame(gdfdict)
   map_df = gpd.read_file(shp)
   map_df['KOD'] = map_df['KOD'].astype(int)
   merge = map_df.merge(df, left_on = 'KOD', right_on = 'Kod')
   fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize = (40, 20))
   cmap = mpl.cm.YlGn
   norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin = vmin, vmax = vmax)
   cb = plt.colorbar(mpl.cm.ScalarMappable(norm = norm, cmap = cmap), orientation = 'vertical', format = mpl.ticker.FuncFormatter(format_ticks))
   cb.set_label(label = label_name(code_name), size = 20)
   merge.plot(column = colm_var, cmap = map_color, linewidth = 0.2, ax = ax, edgecolor = '0.5')
   ax.set_title(map_name(colm_var), fontdict = {'fontsize': '35', 'fontweight' : '10'})
   ax.axis('off')
   name_of_map = "Linear" + colm_var + ".png"
   plt.savefig(path_script + "/Mapy/" + name_of_map, dpi=100)
   plt.clf()
   gc.collect()
   print(objgraph.show_growth())
   print(psutil.Process(os.getpid()).memory_info().rss / 1024 ** 2)
```

Does anybody know what is wrong, and possibly how to fix it?

Thank you

Comment: Really hard to tell without your code.  Did you try *not* plotting the figure, but keeping the rest of the loop the same?  i.e. comment out everything after `fig, ax = ...` and see if the memory leak still persists?  For instance in the above you have a bunch of globals which as far as I can tell could easily be growing in memory depending on how large `data` is.

Comment: Hi, I tryed the commenting as you sugested - 99% of the memory increase and than leak is caused by this line `plt.savefig(path_script + "/Mapy/" + name_of_map, dpi=100)` , but I can't figure out why. When I have `plt.clf()`, 
   `gc.collect()` and now also `plt.close('all')` after the `plt.savefig`, I thought it should clear the memory from the fig, but somehow it is stucked in it.

Comment: I think that the stuck in memory is caused somehow by fact that there are two plots in `fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize = (40, 20))` and it erase at the end just one of it. Not sure by it and I don't even know how to find out, because "fig" and "ax" aren't accesible after the loop.

Comment: Its really hard to tell without all your code.  Suggest you try and make a minimal reproducible example and that will either make things obvious or will give us something to work with.  I suspect you are not closing all your figures.

Answer (score 0):

You may try both plt.clf() and plt.cla()(clearing both figures and axes respectivelly).If this doesnt work a fast (maybe a bit execution time costly) is to run your function as a different process that will die and clear all memory in case of memory leak.

Comment: `plt.cla()` don't have any effect, also `plt.close()`, `plt.close('all)`, `fig.clf()`, etc. However what I found is that the "stucked" memory is proportionaly equal to size of the figure `fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize = (40, 20))` - when I change 40, 20 to 20, 10 and thus make fig 4 times smaller the "stucked" memory is also 4 times smaller. But no further progress so far.